# Laravel collection how to return where no records and not by auth user

Tags: sql, laravel, collections, eloquent

```php
public function tasks(Request $request)
{
    $user = auth::user();
    $query = Task::query();

    $query->with('User')->with('task_type');
    $q = $query->paginate($tasksPerPage);

    foreach ($q as $task) {
        $status = Join::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('task_id', $task->id)->first();
        if ($status['user_id'] === $user->id) {
            $task->current_status = false;
        } else {
            $task->current_status = true;
        }
    }

    return $q;
}
```

How can I return only a task, not by user auth wherein the join no records and not by auth user? How can I only return tasks of an unauthorized user and where there are no records in another table join?

Task.php

```
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $table = 'tasks';
    protected $attributes = ['current_status' => 0];
    protected $visible = ['id', 'name', 'description','user_id', 'task_type_id', 'User','joined','task_type','current_status'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function task_type()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\TaskType', 'id', 'task_type_id');
    }

    public function joined()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Join', 'App\Task', 'id', 'task_id', 'id', 'id');
    }
```

Join.php

```
    public function task()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Task', 'join_task');
    }
        public function user_join()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

Comment: First tips is, you can use `Auth::id()` directly instead of doing `$user = Auth::user(); $user->id` .

Comment: 2nd thing is, it seems your join is wrong, to which table you are making join?

Comment: Is there a need of a Join here? I think you can work it with relationships and using whereHas. If you post your models with some sample data and your expected result i can help you with that

Comment: Yes need join here check if here null

Comment: maybe make accessor for it or where has with relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is

Task.php

```
    public function join()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Join','task_id');
    }
```

TaskController.php

```
 $user = Auth::user();
 $query->where('user_id', '!=', $user->id)
                ->WhereDoesntHave('join', function (Builder $query) use($user){
                $query->where('user_id', 'like', $user->id);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think so you should do go to database inside a loop. it will take more time and its not a good practice at all.

simply do this with `whereHas` you can read about it in the documentation itself [WhereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

for this you can simply do this like following.

```php
    Task::whereHas('User',function($q) use($user_id){
        $q->where('user_id','!=',$user_id);
    })->get();
```

simply it's getting all record which doesn't have current user_id or you can do this for getting all record which match current user_id

```php
    $q->where('user_id',$user_id);
```

Comment: thx... and how make other whereHas with model join ? only task where join(model) null ?

Comment: same proccess you can follow , just use `join` and  `WhereDoesntHave ` method , i suggest you to read documentation, everything will be clear to you